# Use a Ferrers diagram to prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^m{P_k(n)} = P_m(n+m)$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, young-tableaux

I can show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^m{P_k(n)} = P_m(n+m)$ with induction, but I can't figure out how to create an argument based on Ferrers diagrams which proves this equation.

Any hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Start with a Ferrers diagram for a partition of $n+m$ into $m$ parts and remove the leftmost column. What remains is a Ferrers diagram for what? Then show that the correspondence is reversible.

Comment: Ahh, I can't believe I missed that. I did the same proof that you described to show $P(n) = P_n(2n)$ which is just a special case of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}{P_k(n)} = P_m(n+m)$ where $n=m$. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Jeffrey: You’re welcome.